# Como que eu faço para pegar o index de um array usando o valor?

Tags: javascript

Como que eu faço para pegar o index de um array usando o valor?

```
var romanicValue = {'':0,'I':1,'II':2,'III':3,'IV':4,'V':5,'VI':6,'VII':7,'VIII':8,'IX':9,'X':10,'XX':20,'XXX':30,'XL':40,'L':50,'LX':60,'LXX':70,'LXXX':80,'XC':90,'C':100,'CC':200,'CCC':300,'CD':400,'D':500,'DC':600,'DCC':700,'DCCC':800,'CM':900,'M':1000};
```

Comment: Isso é um objeto, não array. E objetos não possuem index

Comment: Ok, mas como eu posso pegar usando um valor? ex. pegar o 'II' usando o valor 2

Comment: Vc tem que iterar pelas chaves até encontrar a que tem o valor que está procurando: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191966

Comment: Foi, muito obrigado